# How to insert latin accents in Math environment

Tags: math-mode, accents

How could I insert accents inside a math environment?

Something like this is what I would like to work:

```
\begin{document}
$ \frac{covariância(A,B)}{desvio-padrão(A) \times desvio-padrão(B)} $
\end{document}
```

Currently, it is giving me an compilation error.

Comment: you can place all "text" in `\text{}` command... like : `\frac{\text{covariância}(A,B)}{\text{desvio-padrão}(A) \times \text{desvio-padrão}(B)}` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
$ \frac{\text{covariância}(A,B)}{\text{desvio-padrão}(A) \times \text{desvio-padrão}(B)} $
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

`[utf8]inputenc` is needed for the accented chars (to be typed directly)

and

`amsmath` offers the `\text{}` command

Comment: Depending on what this is going to be used for, `\textup ` or `\textnormal ` might be better. Just to ward of the possibility of this being used in italic context, and thus not giving the result the OP was probably expecting.

Comment: @daleif you may write your own answer making clear your point of view and the possible advantages. The op had compilation errors, and possibly had not used `inputenc`... Your answer may help other people even if the OP will not change the accepted and thus I think you should write it.

Comment: I don't think it it need to. It is højst better to leave the comment such that s someone later on homes by, uses the solution, gets something they did not expect, this was s probably why. We really need a community question+answer about `\text` so many people use it in the wrong way, or at least is not aware of its pitfalls

Comment: @daleif... Do it. (the question-answer). You have the knowledge and the idea about it... It is just a matter of some minutes to do it.